# iSeries - Call SQL stored procedure from CL program

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, control-language

How can I run a stored procedure from a CL program? RUNSQLSTM requires a source member, but I just want to build a command so users can pass in variables easily, so this won't work.

Answer (score 5):

You can call the system program `QZDFMDB2` and pass it one parameter with the SQL string to execute.  In this case the SQL string is the call to your stored procedure:

```
  CALL PGM(QZDFMDB2) PARM('CALL PROCEDURE (''XYZ'', ''ABC'')')
```

To substitute in your values use a variable for the PARM:

```
  DCL VAR(&CALL) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(200) 

  CHGVAR VAR(&CALL) 
  VALUE('CALL PROCEDURE (''' *CAT &PARM1 *TCAT ''', ''' *CAT &PARM2 *TCAT ''')')

  CALL PGM(QZDFMDB2) PARM(&CALL)
```

Comment: To indicate the location or the library of the procedure, here's a sample: `CALL PGM(QZDFMDB2) PARM('CALL LIBRARY.PROCEDURE (''XYZ'', ''ABC'')')`

Answer (score 3):

There may be 2 options:

In the CL program create a temporary source member. Construct the SQL statement with the supplied parameters to execute the stored procedure and write this source code to the temporary member. Then add a call to RUNSQLSTM with the generated member as parameter.

A second option is not to create a CL program but use RPG/COBOL. By using embedded SQL the stored procedure can be executed with the parameters. Their values should be passed from the command to the program.

Comment: I think your second idea is best for me - thanks. Would be nice to be able to call a procedure directly though!

Answer (score 2):

At one time, there was a command that someone wrote that I had used. I can't find that reference anymore, but I have two other options:

1. [This article](http://search400.techtarget.com/tip/0,,sid3_gci779945,00.html) uses REXX
2. [This article](http://systeminetwork.com/article/dynamic-embedded-sql-runsql-command-revealed) uses RPG

They both include the source you need to get the command working.

Answer (score 1):

One way to call a StoredProcedure from CLLE is:
RUNSQL SQL('call MYPRCSQL')

Comment: Yeah, the relatively new RUNSQL command sounds like exactly what the asker was looking for. After all, it's basically like RUNSQLSTM except the SQL statement is inline rather than in a separate member. It simply wasn't available back in 2008, which is why there are a variety of other approaches mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

`QCMDEXC` might be the command you are looking for.